# Loaded event will not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, events, visual-studio-2013, wpf-controls

We have a huge building issue with our project (WPF). We had a custom control with a loaded event. This event will not fire when I build the project. However, if my co-worker builds the same project everything is fine, the loaded event is fired.

But we don't know why the same project (got the file from git) is broken. It's the same source code and the same project properties (both in `debug` and `release` mode). The only difference is the VS version.
I'm using VS2013 Pro and he is usingh VS2013 Express.

Comment: Can you make sure their are both being compiled in the same architecture? either x86 or x64?

Comment: Both any CPU with "prefer 32 bit"

Comment: Can you edit and attached the console trace? Are you getting an error, can you share that error?

Comment: 'DashBoard.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DashBoard.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationCore.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileFormatException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Comment: ok ignore my question. Found a bug in a external dll which causes the issue :)